# Installing a web server on Ubuntu Snappy Core

Tags: webserver, ubuntu-core

I acknowledge that this question may have been asked before, although I am asking it again because no good answers were given and it has been a while since it has had any activity (about 2 years).

I need to know how to install a web server (probably a LAMP server) on Ubuntu Snappy core (for a RPi 3) to host the development code for a website I am working on, although I don't know how to install it without the use of the apt package manager. I think that the  only way to do it would be to re-package each program as a snap, although I have no clue how to do this. Any help or advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want an updated answer to a question, [post a bounty.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/12120/158442)

Comment: I think my question is a bit different than the one I saw as mine is asking for a more specific answer... while the other one accepted a very general answer.

Comment: Then the least you can do is link to their general answer and specify the shortcomings.

Answer (score 0):

As I do not use Ubuntu Core myself, I googled a bit and found some sources which say that it was possible to activate apt-get for Ubuntu Core in older versions, but not for the current one.

Depending on your preferences and your main operating system, maybe it is also a good alternative to put the code for development on your main machine, like your desktop pc or your laptop, and develop from there.

That is my current setup and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to make some assumptions because I couldn't find any good information about Ubuntu Core.

Assuming that you have access to snaps, you could install Docker with
`snap install docker`

From here you should be able to run you webserver using docker images in docker hub.
You can pull the image with `docker pull httpd:latest` this image is compatible with ARM cpus.

It might take a bit of homework if you are not familiar with docker.